# How to find the correct surface area of rotation

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi I am trying to find the surface area that is traced when the curve $8y^2=x^2-x^4$ is revolved about the $x$-axis. But I am having some trouble with it.

I know that for this in general I will want to use that about the x axis,

$$S= 2\pi \int_{C} y dS $$

I graphed the curve so I see what it looks like; a figure eight type shape with $x$ going from $-1$ to $1$.

But my issue is how I should find $y(t)$.
 I think I could probably use symmetry to simplify as well. Can anyone help with this please?

It seems that there are some discrepancies with different answers from different users, leaving me feeling quite confused. I am still wondering, can no one answer this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using symmetry as you suggest, and using $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the first quadrant,

$\displaystyle S=2\int_0^12\pi r(x)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx=2\int_0^1 2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}x\sqrt{1-x^2}\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{8}\frac{(1-2x^2)^2}{1-x^2}}dx$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{8}}\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2+\frac{1}{8}(1-2x^2)^2}dx$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=\frac{4\pi}{8}\int_0^1 x\sqrt{8-8x^2+1-4x^2+4x^4}\;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1x\sqrt{4x^4-12x^2+9}\;dx$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1x\big|2x^2-3\big|dx$.  $\;\;\;$(Now simplify and integrate.)

---

Alternate solution:  $\;\;$Using symmetry, and the parametrization

$x=\cos t, \;y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\sin t\cos t,\; 0\le t\le\frac{\pi}{2},$ for the part of the curve in Quadrant I gives

$\displaystyle S=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}2\pi r(t)\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} 2\pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\sin t\cos t\right)\sqrt{\sin^2 t+\frac{1}{8}(\cos^2 t-\sin^2 t)^2} dt$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=\frac{4\pi}{8}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(\sin t\cos t)\sqrt{8\sin^2t+(1-2\sin^2 t)^2}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(\sin t\cos t)\sqrt{(1+2\sin^2 t)^2}dt$

$\hspace{.2 in}\displaystyle=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(\sin t\cos t)(1+2\sin^2 t)dt$.  $\hspace{.2 in}$ (Now use $u=1+2\sin^2t, du=4\sin t\cos t dt$.)

Comment: Thanks, why does this come out as a diffirent answer then that of Harish?

Answer (score 0):

Notice, consider an elementary right triangle with hypotenuse $dS$ & legs $dx$ & $dy$ then one should have, 
$$dS=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\ dx=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-2x^3}{8y}\right)^2}\ dx$$
$$=\frac{x\sqrt{7-4x^2-4x^4}}{8y}\ dx$$
hence, the surface area of the solid $$2\pi\int_Cy\ dS=2\pi\int y\cdot \frac{x\sqrt{7-4x^2-4x^4}}{8y}\ dx$$
$$=\frac\pi4\int x\sqrt{7-4x^2-4x^4}\ dx$$
$$=\frac\pi4\int 2 x\sqrt{2-\left(x^2-\frac 12\right)^2}\ dx$$
let, $x^2-\frac 12=t\implies 2x\ dx=dt$,

$$=\frac\pi4\int\sqrt{2-t^2}\ dt$$

Comment: are you using symetry or going from -1 to 1?

Comment: yes, the given curve: $8y^2=x^2-x^4$ is symmetrical in first & third quadrants hence use limit from $0$ to $1$ & double the integral due to symmetry.

Comment: Thanks but why cannot I parametrize and solve for dS ?

Comment: for example I thought for this case the dS was not the square root of 1+ deravative squared , but the square root of x(t) and y(t) dervatives squared

Comment: Thank you but why does your answer differ from the one given by the other user?